# Parse complex json data into material-ui table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

Parse the below complex json data into material-ui table as shown in the example.
The row may contain single value in one and multiple rows on single box as well.
Please find the attempt i made i am able to get the data upto 2 columns.
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/complex-table-g47yw)

```
"identifier": {
        "IOS": {
            "A": {
                "split": 90,
                "return_value": {
                    "xg-boost-x1": 30,
                    "xg-boost-x2": 50,
                    "xg-boost-x3": 20
                }
            },
            "B": {
                "split": 10,
                "return_value": {
                    "xg-boost-x1": 30,
                    "xg-boost-x2": 50,
                    "xg-boost-x3": 20
                }
            }
        },
        "ANDROID": {
            "A": {
                "split": 70,
                "return_value": {
                    "xg-boost-x1": 30,
                    "xg-boost-x2": 50,
                    "xg-boost-x3": 20
                }
            },
            "B": {
                "split": 30,
                "return_value": {
                    "xg-boost-x1": 30,
                    "xg-boost-x2": 50,
                    "xg-boost-x3": 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Final Output Expected]

Comment: You need to at least make an attempt and post the code for us to help you.

Comment: Oh I did make an attempt but I thought it wouldn't be helpful to post an unsuccessful attempt. I will add though.

Comment: that would be more helpful than the picture posted, actually.

Comment: @user1538301 I have added codesanbox url, can you please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution but I am not sure if it is the right way to approach the problem.

Table headers:

```
const headers = [
"IDENTIFIER",
"SYMBOL",
"SPLIT",
"KEY",
"VALUE"
];
```

Util functions:

```
const getTotalSpanSize = key => {
    let size = 1;
    let t = Object.keys(data["identifier"][key]);
    size += t.length;

    t.forEach(i => {
        let d = Object.keys(data["identifier"][key][i]["return_value"]);
        size += d.length;
    });

    return size;
};

const getReturnValueSpanSize = (key, sym) => {
    let size = 1;
    let d = Object.keys(data["identifier"][key][sym]["return_value"]);
    size += d.length;
    return size;
};
```

The component code:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  <Table id="split_table" size="small">
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {headers.map(text => (
          <TableCell key={text}>{text}</TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {Object.keys(data["identifier"]).map(key => (
        <Fragment key={key}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell
              component="th"
              scope="row"
              rowSpan={getTotalSpanSize(key)}
            >
              {key}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          {Object.keys(data["identifier"][key]).map(s => (
            <Fragment key={s}>
              <TableRow key={s}>
                <TableCell
                  scope="row"
                  rowSpan={getReturnValueSpanSize(key, s)}
                >
                  {s}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell
                  scope="row"
                  rowSpan={getReturnValueSpanSize(key, s)}
                >
                  {data["identifier"][key][s].split}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              {Object.keys(data["identifier"][key][s]["return_value"]).map(
                (r, i) => (
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell scope="row">{r}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell scope="row">
                      {data["identifier"][key][s]["return_value"][r]}
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                )
              )}
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```